# no hace post a la base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, html, base-de-datos, vue.js

tengo un pequeño problema basico
e estado creando varios crud y hay uno en el  cual tengo un problema pero no logro identificarlo tengo una ventana modal la cual recolecta los datos
este es el codigo de la ventana modal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de la funcion en el js que utlizo para hacer el post en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el error que me sale en consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y esta es la linea que me manda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Roberto. El código es mejor como texto.

Comment: El problema de un error 500 lo tienes en el archivo que recibe los datos de la petición que estas haciendo, en este caso apiAlmacen, pues es un Internal Server Error... es alli donde debes depurar lo que te está ocurriendo al recibir los datos.

Comment: En el mensaje de la consola te esta indicando en la ultima parte donde analiza el apiIngrediente.js que no esta encontrando una columna, puede ser que no este cargando el valor si lo esta haciendo desde la BD, o que la variable no lleve nada si estas pasando valores por variables o pase de parámetros.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.